Who should I ask if I need further information about the submission guidelines of a journal?
Who should I ask if I want some further information about journal policies? I found something unclear in the author guideline of a journal in which I am interested in. I think the editor in chief is not the one I should ask. The only choice left on their editorial board is the "managing editor," is this the person I should contact?

What is your question about? Are you asking about formatting, or something else?

Is there no contact form? Many journals have one. See e.g. https://authorsupport.wiley.com/s/contactsupport

It is recommended to contact the Editorial Team.
You will access the "about the magazine" part, then click on contacts, there you will find the main contact and the contact for technical support, contact the main contact.
Indicate, in the email, that you have carefully read the guidelines for authors, but still have questions, then say what the question was.
